# Laptop will not connect directly to router, but works on wireless

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, internet-connection

I've got a strange issue which I cannot find a solution to yet. I have a work laptop which I've never got to successfully connect to my router directly (wired). It will connect to the wireless network on the same router, just fine. I also have a wireless range extender setup and it connects to that as well.

When I am connected directly to the router, I am unable to access or ping any websites. I can access my routers admin page, when connected directly so I am able to check router settings, upgrade firmware...etc. It, along with Windows, says I am connected to the internet when connected directly.

I know the NIC card is working because when I work from my office, I use the wired connection there, which works without issue.

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate, and have a Asus RT-N65R router. My NIC card is an integrated Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller. I have upgraded my router to the latest firmware and the problem still exists. I know my network cable is OK since it works when I connect another device like a TV or DVD player to my router. I have a spare laptop that I've had for years which also connects to my router directly without issue.

Please help, I'm out of ideas! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a statically assigned IP address on your NIC?

Comment: No, my network adapter is set to DHCP, but I did just notice that on the IPv4 properties for that NIC card, it seems to be set to a static DNS server.  Could that that be the problem?

Comment: based on your troubling shooting already, its your router at home. if it works at your work, and doesn't at home. well? try hard resetting the router.

Comment: I removed the static DNS settings on the NIC card properties and that resolved the issue.